# Siunitx column removes my spaces unexpectedly

Tags: tables, siunitx

When I try to align the second column of my table with the (first or second) decimal point, the spaces are removed unexpectedly. How can I keep the spaces in "F(XXX, XXX) = XXX"?

Aligning the column with the equal sign (=) is also good to me.

Thanks!

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tgheros}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
    detect-all,
    detect-mode,
    group-separator         = {},
    group-four-digits       = true,
    tight-spacing           = true,
    input-signs             = ,
    input-symbols           = ,
    input-open-uncertainty  = ,
    input-close-uncertainty = ,
    table-align-text-pre    = false,
    table-align-text-post   = false,
    table-space-text-pre    = {(},
    table-space-text-post   = {)},
    input-decimal-markers   = {.},
    table-number-alignment  = right
}

\usepackage[font = {sf, bf}, labelsep = period]{caption}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\DeclareFloatFont{tablefont}{\sffamily\footnotesize}
\floatsetup[table]{font = tablefont, capposition = top}
\floatsetup[figure]{font = tablefont}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Test}
\begin{tabular}{lS}
\toprule
AAA & F(2, 304.20) = 6.85 \\
BBB & F(2, 477.27) = 6.41 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Which decimal point? You have two of them, don't you?

Comment: Either of them is fine. To make the question easier, I hope to align the column with the equal sign "=" and keep the spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea to cram information about both the type of test (here: some kind of F-test, right?) and the value of the test statistic in one and the same column. You're certainly not doing your readers any favor by following this approach.

I suggest you use two columns and employ the `S` column type only for the test statistics.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tgheros}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    detect-all,
    %detect-mode,
    group-separator         = {},
    group-four-digits       = true,
    tight-spacing           = true,
    input-signs             = ,
    input-symbols           = ,
    input-open-uncertainty  = ,
    input-close-uncertainty = ,
    table-align-text-pre    = false,
    table-align-text-post   = false,
    table-space-text-pre    = {(},
    table-space-text-post   = {)},
    input-decimal-markers   = {.},
    table-number-alignment  = right
}

\usepackage[font = {sf, bf}, labelsep = period]{caption}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\DeclareFloatFont{tablefont}{\sffamily\footnotesize}
\floatsetup[table]{font = tablefont, capposition = top}
\floatsetup[figure]{font = tablefont}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Test}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} ll S[table-format=1.2] @{}}
\toprule
AAA & F(2, 304.20) & 6.85 \\
BBB & F(2, 477.27) & 6.41 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, I am doing F-tests. The original table actually has many columns (not just two), so cramming "F(XXX, XXX) = XXX" into a single column would be better.

I tried to define a new column using the dcolumn package:

\newcolumntype{Q}{D{=}{\mskip \thickmuskip=\mskip \thickmuskip}{12.6}}

This Q column solves my problem. Unfortunately, it cannot show sans serif fonts. So I changed back to S column. If the Q column can show sans serif fonts, I can consider using it.

Comment: @FrankKKK - If you simply must "join" the type of test and its value with an `=` symbol -- which, by the way, is a highly dubious practice (aside: I'm an econometrician) -- you could change `\begin{tabular}{@{} ll S[table-format=1.2] @{}}` to `\begin{tabular}{@{} l r @{=} S[table-format=1.2] @{}}`.

Comment: Thanks. After trying your solution (\begin{tabular}{@{} l r @{=} S[table-format=1.2] @{}}), I found there was no space before and after "=". How can I add a space before and after "=", respectively?

Comment: @FrankKKK - The code I provided in the comment didn't insert whitespace around the `=` because there is no whitespace around `=` in the screenshot you provided. It would appear that I shouldn't have interpreted your screenshot in this way. To have the `=` symbols surrounded by, say, thinspace, just replace `@{=}`with `@{\,=\,}`. (The macro `\,` inserts thinspace in both text and math mode.) You mentioned earlier that your "real" table contains lots of columns; that's why I'm not suggesting to insert more than thinspace around the `=` symbols.

Comment: You are right. My attached picture actually indicates the undesired result. Your solution works well for me. Thanks, Mico. But I slightly change the "\," macro to "\thickspace", according to https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Spacing_in_math_mode.

For relational operators, such as <, > and =, LaTeX establishes \thickmuskip space.

Comment: @FrankKKK - In the end, you’re of course free to do whatever you want. However, since (i) the material in a `tabular` environment is processed in text mode, not math mode, by default (including the `=` symbols), (ii) you’ve indicated that horizontal space is not abundant, and (iii) you’ve already chosen to violate several other typographic rules of thumb, you really needn’t feel bound by the TeX-specific convention of surrounding the text-mode `=` symbols with thickspace…